# How to check if the actual function exists using MethodByName?

Tags: go, reflection, error-handling

I am using reflection as a quick & dirty script handler but I can't figure out the error checking

How do I check that MethodByName has found a valid method?

Docs say zero value - what zero value?

anybody able to  help?

https://play.golang.org/p/ogypx-wLay

```
type step struct {
  Action    string
  Parameter string
  Second    string
}

func doStep(little step) (err error) {
  apiR := reflect.ValueOf(skript{})

  apiF := apiR.MethodByName(little.Action)
  if apiF == reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(skript.Approve)) {
    return errors.New("xxx")
  }
  args := []reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(little.Parameter), reflect.ValueOf(little.Second)}
  apiF.Call(args)
  return nil
}

type skript struct{}

func (skript) Approve(who string, dummy string) {
  fmt.Println("Approve ", who, dummy)
}

func main() {
  st1 := step{"Approve", "me", "ok"}
  st2 := step{"Block", "me", "ok"}
  doStep(st1)
  doStep(st2)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From standard docs:

> The zero Value represents no value. Its IsValid method returns false, its Kind method returns Invalid, its String method returns ""

So you want to use the IsValid method on the returned value from MethodByName. If it's false there was an error.

Comment: Aww... too slow. Good answer :)

Comment: Thanks - a lot better than 
     if apiF.Kind() != reflect.Func 

which I was trying

Comment: @DaveAppleton the reason that wasn't working was because `Zero` was creating a zero `Value` but, of course, they wouldn't `==` each other because it was creating a NEW zero `Value`.